# How to connect the "show" and "hide" signals with PyGTK?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I would like to have a callback called when some widget (a `Menu`) is shown or hidden. Doing this way :

```
menu = gtk.Menu()
menu.connect("show", self.menu_show, menu)
menu.connect("hide", self.menu_hide, menu)
```

Callback functions are never called. Are `show` and `hide` signals the ones I am looking for ? Are they special ? Is there something I am missing to have this working ?

Comment: How do you "show" or "hide" this menu? do you use the menu.popup method?

Comment: I don't have control over this part, it's for an Ubuntu application indicator: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators (see the Python code snippet at the bottom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think those signals are emitted only when the respective methods on an object are called. If you want to connect to when a widget is (re-) drawn, take the expose-event signal. But why do you want to anyway? A menu is there to provide to the user choices for actions, not to run some setup/teardown code when it is shown/hidden.

Comment: The context is quite particular, the menu content must be refreshed every second. I want this periodic refresh to happen only when needed, ie when the menu is visible to the user.

Comment: I'm not sure but "visibility-notify-event" should probably do it.

Comment: Just tried connecting all signals from Widget. None of them work, so I am probably missing something obivous here. Only the "activate" events on the Menu items work.

Comment: Why not connect to a menuitem: if it is visible that is the same thing as if the menu is visible, right?

Comment: After looking into it, all those limitations are inherent to Ubuntu AppIndicators... See http://askubuntu.com/questions/16431/putting-an-arbitrary-gtk-widget-into-an-appindicator-indicator/18364#18364 . Thanks for the help anyway !